# Trying to solve If/else problem with specific string and boolean

Tags: javascript, if-statement

**Problem**

I've tried multiple avenues and watched videos. I'm stuck...

```
function exerciseThree(typeOfPizza){
  let lovesPizza;
  // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: typeOfPizza
  // You are also given another variable called: lovesPizza;
  // Using an if/else statement assign lovesPizza to true if typeOfPizza is 'pepperoni', assign it to false if it is 'olives'
```

What I've tried:

```
if (lovesPizza==='pepperoni') {
    // The value is empty.
    return true;
}
else {
    (lovesPizza==='olives')
    return false;
}
```

Another attempt

```
 // if(lovesPizza===pepperoni){
  //  return true
  //}
  //else (lovesPizza===olives){
  //  return false
//  }
```

Another one

```
  //if (lovesPizza.equals(pepperoni))
    //  return "true";
  //else (lovesPizza.equals(olives))
    //  return "false"
```

Comment: if you want a different condition after `else`, then you need another `if`, so you'll do `if (condition1) {} else if (condition2) {}`

Comment: Also, you're supposed to compare `typeOfPizza`, not `lovesPizza`.

Comment: Pay attention to the wording: *"assign lovesPizza to true **if typeOfPizza is 'pepperoni'**"*. You're checking the wrong variable.

Comment: You're also returning instead of assigning `lovesPizza` to `true/false`

Comment: Thanks georg for pointing that out. That did the trick. Stupid typo!

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, you're looking for [if / else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#Description). You should also double check your reading of the question, you had your checking / assigning variables the wrong way around

```js
    function exerciseThree(typeOfPizza){
        let lovesPizza;

        if (typeOfPizza === 'pepperoni') {
            lovesPizza = true;
        } else if (typeOfPizza === 'olives') {
            lovesPizza = false;
        }

        console.log('lovesPizza:', lovesPizza);
    };
    
    exerciseThree('pepperoni');
    exerciseThree('olives');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using a switch statement in this case here. Switch statements run faster and are easier to work with in my opinion.

But to point out what you're doing wrong:

Here you are checking if lovesPizza has the value of pepperoni. But you should be checking typeOfPizza. This is why you're most likely getting undefined:

```
if (lovesPizza==='pepperoni') {
    // The value is empty.
    return true;
}
else {
    (lovesPizza==='olives')
    return false;
}
```

Check out how this looks with a switch statement.

```js
function exerciseThree(typeOfPizza) {
     switch (typeOfPizza) {
      case 'pepperoni':
       return true;
      case 'olives':
       return false;
      default:
       return false;
     }
   }
   exerciseThree('pepperoni');
   exerciseThree('olives');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your else statement needs an if

```
if(somethingisTrue)
  {
   return "it is true";
  }
else if(somethingelseistrue)
  {
    return "no the other thing was true";
   }
else
  {
    return "nothing is true"
  }
```

Also === checks the strings equal and are both strings. It is often better to make sure the if is case insensative

```
if(!typeOfPizza)
    {
       //raise an error as null was passed in
       return "false"
    }
 else if(typeOfPizza.toLowerCase().trim()==="pepperoni"){
    {
      return true..... you can build the rest
```

I often write a function (prototype) called cleanString or compareString to perform all the normal cleaning up of strings.

A simple solution is but doesn't use ifs as asked.

```
function exerciseThree(typeOfPizza){
    let lovesPizza= typeOfPizza==="pepperoni";
    return lovesPizza;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I certainly hope you teacher is playing a trick on you. 
There is no sane suggestions what to do if you send for instance 'ham' into it, and not handle all possibilities are just sloppy.

```
let lovesPizza;

function exerciseThree(typeOfPizza){
  if(typeOfPizza === 'pepperoni') {
    return true;
  } else if (typeOfPizza === 'olives') {
    return false;
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
}

lovesPizza = exerciseThree('pepperoni');
console.log(lovesPizza); // true
lovesPizza = exerciseThree('olives');
console.log(lovesPizza); // false
lovesPizza = exerciseThree('ham');
console.log(lovesPizza); // undefined
```